# Parse HTML Table in PowerShell V3

Tags: powershell, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML table [Link To the HTML](http://pastebin.com/kyy9rMJZ)

I want to parse it and convert it to XML/CSV/PS Object,
I tried to do with HtmlAgilityPack.dll but no success.
Can anybody give me any directions to do it?

---

I want to convert the table to a PSObject and export it to csv, 
I currently have just the beginning of the code, 
and access to the lines but i can't access to the values in the lines

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\system32\HtmlAgilityPack.dll
$HTML = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$res = $HTML.Load("C:\Test\Test.html")
$table = $HTML.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td/nobr")
```

when i access to $table[0..47].InnerHtml i get only the first ** column ** of the file, 
i can't access to the 2nd and etc

Thanks Ohad

Comment: What exactly did you try? E.g. we'd like to see code, error messages or anything actionable. HTML Agility Pack doesn't yield XML objects but rather its own structure that mimics the XML DOM tree. Keep in mind that HTML is often *not* XML. Why do you desperately need XML here?

Comment: P.S: i need to convert it to XML or CSV even a text can be helpfull for me

Comment: If you get your HTML via Invoke-WebRequest it gives a parsedHTML property using which you can traverse the DOM and convert to the format you wish to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this  to get all the html in `<nobr>` tags. I let you find the logic to output what you want...

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://urltoyourfile.html")
$doc = $ie.Document
($doc.getElementsByTagName("nobr"))|%{$_.innerHTML}
```

Output :

```
Lead User&nbsp;&nbsp;
Accesses&nbsp;&nbsp;
Last Accessed&nbsp;&nbsp;
Average&nbsp;&nbsp;
Max&nbsp;&nbsp;
Min&nbsp;&nbsp;
Total&nbsp;&nbsp;
amirt</NO br>
2
01/20/2013 09:40:47
04:18:17
06:19:26
02:17:09
08:36:35
andream
1
01/20/2013 10:33:01
02:34:37
02:34:37
02:34:37
02:34:37
avnerm
1
01/17/2013 11:34:16
00:30:44
00:30:44
00:30:44
00:30:44
brouria
```

a way to parse it :

```
($doc.getElementsByTagName("nobr"))|%{
    write-host -nonew $_.innerHTML";"
    $cpt++
    if ($cpt % 8 -eq 0){$cpt=1;write-host ""}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it open the IE and not giving any output to powershell

Comment: maybe because i have my file localy?
win7? IE9?

Comment: nope i've tried with UNC and works too : `$ie.navigate("\\server\test\test.html")`

Comment: Great it was UAC... Just need to run as admin the powershell 
:)
Thanks i'll try to parse it now