# Convert HTML file into .CSV using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, csv

So I have an HTML file generated from a 3rd-party that gets e-mailed to me (and my group) daily. It contains a table of ID no's, Names, and multiple e-mail addresses if applicable. It is used to update group membership in AD and I would like to be able to do this in powershell since the group membership update portion is easy. The parsing HTML file to pull e-mail addresses, which are also their AD usernames, is the tough part. I'm kinda at a stump. I've tried using HTMLAgilityParser which doesn't seem to work all that great for my purpose. If I could somehow get the data into a .CSV for ease of use that would be great.

What I need is to either A) Pull the e-mail addresses directly from the HTML and place them in a CSV file or B) Convert the HTML file to a .CSV to be parsed.

The reason is that this data comes in daily so this will have to be automated.

Thanks!

Sample from the html file, all identifying info has been removed and/or adjusted:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class=xl27>
<span class=font7>ID</span>
</td>
<td class=xl27>
<span class=font7>Name</span>
</td>
<td class=xl27>
<span class=font7>Primary E-Mail</span>
</td>
<td class=xl27>
<span class=font7>Alternate E-Mail</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=xl28>
<span class=font8>00000000</span>
</td>
<td class=xl28>
<span class=font8>Smith,John R</span>
</td>
<td class=xl28>
<span class=font8></span>
</td>
<td class=xl28>
<span class=font8>John_Smith@addr</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of how the html file looks like?

Comment: That wasn't formatted correctly at all... editting into original post

Comment: update your question with the code and proper formatting.

Comment: If I could get a powershell script or line of powershell to read this and just output the actual data, I could use the Export-CSV cmdlet to just write the file.

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496951/parse-html-table-in-powershell-v3

Comment: Yea I have. it doesn't work correctly. I create the custom PSObject and use the HTMLAgility pack to attempt to parse out the data. But the data that is being stored isn't correct. It is only supposed to get 4 columns of data, I was getting 14 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the beginning of a solution, not so good ...
It supposes that HtmlAgilityPack.dll is in Html-Agility-Pack directory of the directory script file.

```
Add-Type -Path "$(Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath)\Html-Agility-Pack\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"


$webGraber = New-Object -TypeName HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
$webDoc = $webGraber.Load("C:\temp\t.htm")
$trDatas = $webDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Elements("tr")

Remove-Item "c:\temp\t.csv"

foreach ($trData in $trDatas)
{
  $tdDatas = $trData.elements("td")
  $line = ""
  foreach ($tdData in $tdDatas)
  {
    $line = $line + $tdData.InnerText.Trim() + ','
  }
  $line.Remove($line.Length -1) | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\t.csv" -Append
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I added the direct path to the .dll on my PC in place and I am getting nothing for output. What version of .net and powershell are you using? My issue is probably that I'm using powershell v1.0... I'm going to update and try again

Comment: I updated and attempted once again. It looks to me that the HTML file is not being loaded since I'm getting invokemethodonNull errors when setting the $trDatas variable.

Comment: Yes I test it. I'am using PowerShell 3.0. Are you sure you tha you are using PowerShell 1.0 (XP ?)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I did update to 3.0 and .net 4.5 and I made sure I was using the net45 Html Agility Pack .dll

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to post this answer as it is extremely specific to this case, but this can be accomplished with simple string methods. First get the content of the html file:

```
$htmlContent = Get-Content -Path 'thePath\andFile.html'
```

Next select the strings from the html data that contain the values you are looking for. This part is absolutely specific to the structure of your html:

```
$stringsWithDesiredValues = $htmlContent.Where({$_ -like '*<span class=font8>*'})
```

Now we can use a foreach and use the indices of '>' and '<' to get a substring with only the desired values.

```
foreach($htmlString in $stringsWithDesiredValues){
$firstIndex = $htmlString.IndexOf('>') + 1
$lastIndex = $htmlString.LastIndexOf('<')
$lengthOfSubstring = $lastIndex - $firstIndex
$desiredValue = $htmlString.Substring($firstIndex,$lengthOfSubstring)
$desiredValue}
```

Of course I'm not doing anything with the desired value here, but this script will write out the values so you can see that they are correct. You can obviously capture those values in the loop and do with them what you will. An ugly solution to be sure, I only posted it because no other answers suggested.